# How I can activate\enable and object after my tag will collide with a certain force or speed (VR game - UNITY 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a VR game.
Is a fighting game, the player will be able the punch the enemies (on his fist will be a collider and a disabled object with the damage script).
I need a script that will activate another object (the one with damage script) - (placed on his fist) but just on certain speed or force (you know, like in real life- if the enemy will be touched with the hand he should not be damaged, just on high force or speed)
What is the best solution?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your player's fist is not being controlled by the physics system, it will not be possible to read the velocity of the player's hand like you would a normal Rigidbody. That being said, you can still calculate the speed and handle all of what you wish to do in one script.

Here's an example:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(DamageScript))]
public class HandSpeedMonitor : Monobehaviour
{
    public float threshold;
    DamageScript damageScript;
    Vector3 lastPos;

    public void Awake()
    {
        damageScript = this.GetComponent<DamageScript>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        lastPos = this.transform.position;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        float velocity = (lastPos - this.transform.position).magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
        if(!damageScript.enabled && velocity > threshold)
            damageScript.enabled = true;
        else if(damageScript.enabled)
            damageScript.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

However, since .magnitude is an expensive call, you may want to consider storing your "threshold" as a squared speed "sqrThreshold" and use .sqrMagnitude, since it removes the square root component of vector math (saving on processing).

Comment: thank you for your fast reply!
I tested the code, but even I do not move the object , my DamageScript is on and off time to time.Why is doing that?
I change the values also from 0 to ...the same

Comment: If the object is moving a very slight amount over a short time, you could potentially see a high velocity. Try debugging the velocity to the console to see if that's the case. You might need to set a higher threshold.

Comment: I did, but I tink will not work for my case.
Can you give me another solution pls.
Maybe if my hand is reaching a certain speed will activate the Damage?is this a solution.
Like: max speed 100, if my hand will reach 100 speed, the damage is active?

Comment: I am not understanding what you are saying, unfortunately. There is a lot of information missing, and your comments do not provide enough.